# What is the approximation of trigonometric function by simple function

Tags: trigonometry, approximation, trigonometric-series, approximate-integration

for
$f(x)=\sin x$,
$g(x)=\cos x$,
$h(x)=\tan x$,

What is the approximation of each function by using simple function?

Comment: What do you by approximation by simple function?

Comment: what about $\sin x\approx x,|x|<< 1$?

Comment: I recently read from many references that every function $f(x)$ can be approximated by simple function $f_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}c_k1_{A_k}$ where $c_k$ is a constant and $1_{A_k}$ is indicator function. I find many approximation of general function, such as $f(x)=x$, $f(x)=x^3$, etc. but not trigonometric function. Please help.

Comment: Are you saying an step function?

Comment: Yes, step function.

Comment: Why do you want to have an approximation of f,g,h in step function?

Comment: I think it is not comfortable to have it. Because of this kind of function have a lot of points with "bad" fashion. Anyway it is easy to get it, using that the function is continuous you can do it for yourself. Draw a picture!

Comment: I want to prove lebesgue integration of that f,g,h function have the same result with riemann integration of them. So, firstly, i should make an approximation of that functions by simple function (step function). Then, by using Monotone Convergence Theorem, I can find the lebesgue integral of f,g,h function. But unfortunately, I couldn't find what are the approximation of f,g,h functions.

Answer (score 2):

Don you want the following:

$$\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+\cdots$$

$$\cos x=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots $$

Answer (score 2):

Near to zero it is usual to use the following approximation:

$$\sin x \approx x $$
$$\cos x \approx 1-\displaystyle \frac{x^2}{2}$$
$$\tan x \approx x $$

you can convince yourself, for example, using the relationships that @paul gives.

Answer (score 2):

There is a general construction that can be used here. Consider any nonnegative measurable function $f$. Now define

$$A_{n,m} = \left \{ x : \frac{m-1}{n} \leq f(x) \leq \frac{m}{n} \right \}, \quad m = 1,2,\dots,n^2, \\
A_{n,n^2+1} = \{ x : f(x) \geq n \}.$$

Then the sequence of simple functions

$$s_n(x) = \sum_{m=1}^{n^2} \frac{m-1}{n} 1_{A_{n,m}}(x) + n 1_{A_{n,n^2+1}}(x)$$

converge to $f$.

To generalize this to functions which are not nonnegative, apply this construction to $f^+ = \max \{ f,0 \}$ and $f^- = \max \{ -f,0 \}$, obtaining sequences $s_n^+$ and $s_n^-$ respectively. Then take $s_n = s_n^+ - s_n^-$.

Comment: Would you please explain longer and be detail by using the example $f(x)=sinx$ where $x\in[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$?

Comment: I can't be very explicit with it, because then I would need to actually identify the intervals in question, a numerical problem. Still, in the case of $\sin$ on $[\pi/2,\pi]$, you have a nonnegative function, so you don't need to split into $f^+$ and $f^-$. In this case what we are doing is chopping the range of $f$, which on that interval is just $[0,1]$, into $n$ pieces: $[0,1/n],(1/n,2/n],\dots,((n-1)/n,1]$. Then we find the intervals which map into each, and approximate by a function which is constant on each such interval.

Comment: For $\sin$, if you look at the graph, the inverse images wind up being $[x_{k+1},x_k]$ where $x_k$ is the solution to $\sin(x)=k/n$ in the second quadrant. So our approximation function is $k/n$ on each $[x_{k+1},x_k]$ where $k$ ranges from $0$ to $n$.

Comment: This will coincide with the Riemann construction because it actually *is* a Riemann construction: we are approximating the integral of our function by the integral of a function which is piecewise constant. In this case and every other continuous case, the pieces are intervals. The intervals are chosen differently than we usually choose them in Riemann integration, but you hopefully have already seen that this does not matter: the Riemann integral does not depend on the choice of partitions or evaluation points.

Comment: So, the simple approximation of $f(x)=sinx$ is $f_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{k}{n}1_{\{\frac{k}{n}\leq sinx<\frac{k+1}{n}\}}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{k}{n}1_{\{arcsin\frac{k}{n}\leq x<arcsin\frac{k+1}{n}\}}$. Got it. Now, when we use monotone convergence theorem, $\int\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$, it started to be confusing.

Comment: @math-learner Which answer? The proof that this coincides with the Riemann integral? You can already see it: the integral of the simple function is, almost by definition, $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{k}{n} \left ( \left ( \pi - arcsin \frac{k+1}{n} \right ) - \left ( \pi - arcsin \frac{k}{n} \right ) \right )$. (Technically one has to prove that the Lebesgue measure of an interval is its length, but let us assume this has already been done.) But this is a sequence of lower Riemann sums on a particular sequence of partitions of $[\pi/2,\pi]$.

Comment: I got what you were just explaining. Thank you. So, if now we change the interval into $x\in[0,\pi]$, the approximation by simple function is also $\sum_{k=0}^{\pi}\frac{k}{n}(sin^{-1}\frac{k+1}{n}-sin^{-1}\frac{k}{n})$ without any difference with our previous example, but this approximation means lower Riemann sum of $\int_{0}^{\pi}sinxdx$, right??

Comment: For $[0,\pi]$, each inverse image is actually two intervals (for instance, $[\pi-x,\pi]$ and $[0,x]$), but the situation is otherwise essentially the same, you just have to include terms for both pieces.

Answer (score 2):

You can establish quite nice approximations using  Pade expansions of the functions. For example $$\sin(x)\approx \frac{x-\frac{7 x^3}{60}}{1+\frac{x^2}{20}}$$ $$\cos(x)\approx\frac{1-\frac{5 x^2}{12}}{1+\frac{x^2}{12}}$$ $$\tan(x)\approx\frac{x-\frac{x^3}{15}}{1-\frac{2 x^2}{5}}$$ are quite good.

For sure, if you increase the degrees of numerator and denominator, it will be better but more complex. For example $$\sin(x)\approx\frac{x-\frac{31 x^3}{294}}{1+\frac{3 x^2}{49}+\frac{11 x^4}{5880}}$$